# Getting viewCount from XML

Tags: php, xml, youtube-api, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I'm currently using the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) form Google and I'm trying to get the "viewCount" array. I've tried this already with no luck at all. [Here](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gudjondaniel/uploads?max-results=1) is the link that I'm currently using.

I tried this before with no luck at all.

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gudjondaniel/uploads?max-results=1';
$source = file_get_contents($url); 
$xml    = new SimpleXMLElement($source);
$title  = $xml->entry->viewCount;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other people: the OP wants to access the `<yt:statistics favoriteCount="0" viewCount="301" />` node that is a child of `<entry> node`.

Try this (xpath):

```
$file = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gudjondaniel/uploads?max-results=1');
var_dump($file->xpath('//yt:statistics'));
```

You will see this:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#13 (1) {
    public $@attributes =>
    array(2) {
      'favoriteCount' =>
      string(1) "0"
      'viewCount' =>
      string(3) "301"
    }
  }
}
```

edit:

Final code will look like this:

```
$file = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gudjondaniel/uploads?max-results=1');
$xpath = $file->xpath('//yt:statistics');
$attrs = $xpath[0]->attributes();
echo (string) $attrs->viewCount;
```

By the way, SimpleXMLElement is a gibberish-PHP tool that - as you can see - makes it hardly possible to access element like `<yt:statistics>`. Other platforms use xpath as a standard.

Comment: Would it be possible with xpath though ?

Comment: @IamGretar I don't understand above question. In the third line you can see calling xpath method and it works. Just execute this code and you'll see.